# ModernUI Object reference not set

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, modern-ui

[image]

Hi All ;

I see something named ModernUI  and wanted to try it . I downloaded packages from NUGET --> Modern UI and
I added resourceDictionary to App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and my main page is like in the image.
I couldnt understand whats the problem. 
Build result :

Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped

The error part disturbs me ? How can I get rid of them. Thanks (By the way example code from github also has the same problem.)